# why am i seeing this libzdb configure error?

Tags: c++, unix, configure, setjmp

I am attempting to install libzdb on my macbook however I see the following error message when running the configure:
    **configure:13334: error: setjmp is required**

the setjmp.h file resides within */usr/include* and is specified within my *"$PATH"* as

**/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/include**

Can someone please advise as to how i can rectify this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: The environment variable `PATH` is not used by the build system for anything other than finding the compiler/tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally figured it out. For those who have seen messages like this be warned that the configure logs can be misleading. It turned out the binary built fine, however it was failing during runtime because a few mysql libraries could not be found. using the following command *export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/* would fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across this error while building one of my own programs when I wanted to use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`. For some reason, the toolchain that resides in `/` on OS X is flawed, and the `<setjmp.h>` header file is missing the declarations and data types.

To fix it, I had to download Xcode (damn!) and tell the compiler to look for the headers in the freshly installed `MacOSX10.7.sdk` (or 8) folder:

```
clang -Wall -o foo foo.c -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for sharing, i have installed the latest Xcode, however if i run the following: ./configure CPPFLAGS=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk, i see an error much early on complaining that it was unable to produce an executable

Comment: @godzilla Because you haven't read my answer carefully enough.